# How can I calculate an address’s balance with “total recieved”?

Tags: transactions, balance

I want to calculate balances of my customers with a process ,
`total received(I get it via api provided by a Blockchain explorer)-total_sent(I store transactions my customers make)`
 but as you know, total received amounts are different in block explorers, so I wonder if I can calculate balances correctly.

So please let me know proper solutions.

Comment: `total received amounts are different in block explorers` They shouldn't be, total received is simply the sum of every utxo created for that address.

Comment: Block explorers are well known to provide bad information.

Comment: Oh really? As I guess, total recieved is the history of input amounts though